# How to scrape reactive table in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, reactive-programming, reactive

Really new with R here - this is the code I normally use to scrape tables, but I couldn't get it to work due to the table on this website being reactive.

This is the url: https://sgpgrid.com/filter/property-fund-management-including-reit-management-and-direct-property-fund-management

And this is the code chunk I used.

```
library(rvest)

d2 <- read_html("https://sgpgrid.com/filter/property-fund-management-including-reit-management-and-direct-property-fund-management")

stats <- d2 %>%
    html_node(".rt-table") %>%
    html_table()

stats
```

Rstudio keeps showing "Error in html_table.xml_node(.) : html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE" whenever I try to run the code...

Would really appreciate any help here :(

Comment: Most web pages load data with javascript after they are loaded and no not contain all the data in the source HTML code. rvest can only read the raw HTML and cannot run javascript for you. If you need to scrape a webpage that uses javascript, you'll need to use a package like RSelenium instead.

Answer (score 1):

The data is rendered from a JSON object located in a `script` tag (ReactJS local state). You can get this by searching the `script` tag with id `__NEXT_DATA__` :

```
library(rvest)

data <- "https://sgpgrid.com/filter/property-fund-management-including-reit-management-and-direct-property-fund-management" %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes('script#__NEXT_DATA__') %>%
    html_text()

output <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data)

print(output$props$initialState$company$companies)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Could I ask - how did you know the id for the script tag was "__NEXT_DATA__"?

Comment: and how do you identify that the data was rendered from the json object instead of in the source html code?

Comment: @AdelynKoh open chrome development console, go to network tab and refresh. Check the html output of the first call, you will see a big json and identify the location